# SQL recursive CTE timeout on Azure

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure

I have the following view that has serious performance issue when it runs on Azure. If I copy the Azure database locally and run any query on the view it returns in seconds. THe same query on the view times out on Azure.

Why would a query against the view time out on Azure?

```
         CREATE VIEW [dbo].[JobTypeDescendantJobTypes] 
            AS 
            WITH    cte ( ParentJobTypeId, Id ) 
                      AS ( SELECT   Id , 
                                    Id 
                           FROM     dbo.JobTypes 
                           UNION ALL 
                           SELECT   e.Id , 
                                    cte.Id 
                           FROM     cte 
                                    INNER JOIN dbo.JobTypes AS e ON e.ParentJobTypeId = cte.ParentJobTypeId 
                         ) 
            SELECT  ISNULL(Id, 0) AS ParentJobTypeId,
                    ISNULL(ParentJobTypeId, 0) AS Id
            FROM    cte
```

Comment: what is the point of self joining?

Comment: @MitchWheat thanks. How do I go about doing that? Do you see anything obviously wrong with the code?

Comment: It is used for parent child relationships

Answer (score 1):

Rebuild your statistics / indexes.

One way to do this is: **(*NOTE: run with caution in production)**

```
DECLARE @table nvarchar(255) 
DECLARE tablecursor CURSOR FOR
SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_type = 'base table'

OPEN tablecursor 
FETCH NEXT FROM tablecursor INTO @table

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
BEGIN
  exec('ALTER INDEX ALL ON ' + @table + ' REBUILD')
  FETCH NEXT FROM tablecursor INTO @table
END

CLOSE tablecursor 
DEALLOCATE tablecursor
```

Comment: Rebuilding indexes didn't help, is there anything else you can think of?